# PVS-Studio on Linux - pvs_studio_add_target

Tags: cmake, pvs-studio

I'm trying to use the command pvs_studio_add_target to integrate PVS-Studio into my CMake project. Can anybody point me to an example CMakeLists.txt file that does this?

When I build my project I see the following output (apart from the usual stuff):

> Generating PVS-Studio.log: no sources found

I would have assumed that PVS-Studio would look for the project source files in CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR? Maybe I have to tell it that? Here are the modifications that I made to my projects CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(pvs_studio_cmake "$ENV{HOME}/installers/PVS-Studio.cmake")
include(${pvs_studio_cmake})
# TODO: Generating PVS-Studio.log: no sources found
pvs_studio_add_target(TARGET analyze ALL
                      FORMAT tasklist
                      PREPROCESSOR gcc)
```

I run the following command to configure CMake in the build directory (out of source build):

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=On -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug <source-dir>
```

I inserted the following comment into the top of all of my projects cpp files.

```
// This is an independent project of an individual developer. Dear PVS-Studio, please check it.
// PVS-Studio Static Code Analyzer for C, C++ and C#: http://www.viva64.com
```

In this particular project that is just main.cpp. I have some header only files with template code that do not have a corresponding cpp file.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Please reformulate your question. Currently you are asking for an example which is off-topic. Ask "what should I do to achieve X? I tried Y so far and got Z"

Comment: Hi, OK. PVS-Studio does not seem to be finding any files to analyse, hence the message: "Generating PVS-Studio.log: no sources found". I want to know how to fix this. Thanks,

Comment: @David try this test project: http://cppfiles.com/test_project.tar.gz

Comment: @StevenHunter : Hi Steven, I was able to build your test project. It reported the problem: "error: V501 There are identical sub-expressions to the left and to the right of the '==' operator: x == x" . Using the example project as a reference I was able to fix my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the official PVS-Studio repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/viva64/pvs-studio-cmake-examples) you can find the documentation and test examples of analyzer integration with CMake.